# How to copy means values of one column to another if two other column strings match?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to rearrange names within a data frame (shown below), but keep their average scores. So I know I could do the following to get a list of the values for each person:

```
df1.groupby('Person1')['AverageScoreP1'].mean()
df1.groupby('Person2')['AverageScoreP2'].mean()
```

But how could I put them into the new dataframe (df2) in the correct order. I had used the 'transform' method but does not attach the name and their average score as one entity. Instead it just copies the values from df1 into df2 in the same order (shown in df2(Attempted) as shown below). I'm sure this has a simple solution!

df1:

```
Person 1    Person 2    AverageScoreP1   AverageScoreP2

Sam         Ellie       2.3              10.2
James       Sarah       4.5              8.8
Steven      Jane        6.6              3.5
Martin      Becky       7.7              2.0
```

df2:

What I would like to show:

```
Person 1    Person 2    AverageScoreP1   AverageScoreP2

Martin      Sarah       7.7              8.8
Steven      Becky       6.6              2.0
Sam         Ellie       2.3              10.2
James       Jane        4.5              3.5
```

df2 (Attempted):

```
Person 1    Person 2    AverageScoreP1   AverageScoreP2

Martin      Sarah       2.3              10.2
Steven      Becky       4.5              8.8
Sam         Ellie       6.6              3.5
James       Jane        7.7              2.0
```

Comment: How do you rearrange them, what is the point, you want to sort by AverageScoreP1? As far as I undderstand you just want to rearange the table, so scores remain atached to the person you calculated it for. The only question is how do u want to arrange it

Comment: So I have produced df1 with the average scores correctly associated to each name. For 'df2' I have Person 1 and Person 2 columns given to me in an alternative ordering. I want to copy the correct pairing of Person 1 and 2 and their scores from df1 to df2. The actual data is much larger and hence wanted to know a quick way I could do this

Comment: so you have full table df1 and just first two columns of df 2 and you want to complete them, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way(comments inline):

```
df1.columns=df1.columns.str.replace(' ','') #replace spaces, if required create a copy df
d=dict(pd.wide_to_long(df1.reset_index(),['Person','AverageScoreP'],
                 i='index',j='v').values) #create a dict of name and avg score
```

---

---

```
m=df2.replace(d) #replace df2 with dict
m.columns=[i for i in df1.columns if 'Person' not in i] #change col names
df2=df2.join(m) #join with df2
```

---

```
  Person 1 Person 2  AverageScoreP1  AverageScoreP2
0   Martin    Sarah             7.7             8.8
1   Steven    Becky             6.6             2.0
2      Sam    Ellie             2.3            10.2
3    James     Jane             4.5             3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_score1(person1):
    return df1[df1.Person1==person1].AverageScoreP1
def search_score2(person2):
    return df1[df1.Person2==person2].AverageScoreP2,  


df2['search_score1']==df2.apply(lambda x:search_score1(x.Person1),axis=1)
df2['search_score2']==df2.apply(lambda x:search_score2(x.Person2),axis=1)
```

Something like that will do the trick

Comment: @anky_91 why? after discussion in comments it seems exactly like what is needed, I first thought that the question is how to rearange rows, kinda, but you can notice that in df2 pairs are NOT the same as in df1 so you have to separately search for person1 and person2 (EXAMPLE PAIR 1)James + Sarah2)Martin+Sarah